# How to show related div on form search: JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form in which I have a select drop down as follows:

```
<form action="/boat-types/">
  <select id="selectField" class="form-control">
    <option>Boat Type</option>
    <option value="option1">Sail b || Monohull (2-3 cabins)</option>
    <option value="option2">Sail b || Monohull (4 or more cabins)</option>
    <option value="option3">Sail b || Catamaran (2-3 cabins)</option>
    <option value="option4">Sail b || Catamaran (4 or more cabins)</option>
    <option value="option5">Power b || Monohull (2-3 cabins)</option>
    <option value="option6">Power b || Monohull (4 or more cabins)</option>
    <option value="option7">Power b || Catamaran (2-3 cabins)</option>
    <option value="option8">Power b || Catamaran (4 or more cabins)</option>
  </select>
  <div class="find-yacht-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)">Find my yacht</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I have a div to show on each select option are as follows. That means if I select option 1 from drop down then the option 1  will be shown after submitting the form:

```
  <div id="option1" class="box">Content 1</div>
  <div id="option2" class="box">Content 2</div>
  <div id="option3" class="box">Content 3</div>
  <div id="option4" class="box">Content 4</div>
```

I have tried the following solution but not showing after submitting the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#option1').show();
  $('#selectField').change(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Submitting the form reloads the page, all scripts stop.

Comment: Your code shows the DIV when the user selects the corresponding item from the dropdown. It doesn't do anything special when the form is submitted.

Comment: You shouldn't have to perform a submit here, unless you want the user to perform that specific action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to submit form without reloading page, which is preffered option in your case. Other way is to save selected option in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), and retrieve it on page load.